# CSS - Match a whole attribute value

Tags: css, attributes, match

**HTML**

```
<div data-whatever='something cols-16 else'>
</div>
```

This works:

**Will work - CSS**

```
[data-whatever*='cols-1'] {
    background: red;
}
```

It will find the div and make it red.

**Will not work - CSS**

```
[data-whatever='cols-16'] {
    background: red;
}
```

It will not find the div because there are other stuff in there as well.

**Problem**

The problem with the working CSS, is that it matches both `cols-16`, `cols-1` and any other that starts with `cols-1`.

**Question**

Is it possible to find an attribute value, exact match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to target the class cols-16 (even when it appears with other classes)

and not target the cols-1 class use this:

```
[data-whatever~='cols-16'] {
    background: green;
}
```

You can see this working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gKysf/).

For more info see this [post](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) (Goto #16. - X[foo~="bar"]

> The tilda (~) symbol allows us to target an attribute which has a
>   spaced-separated list of values.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[data-whatever~='cols-1'] {
    background: red;
}
```

It worked for me if I didn't missunderstand your question

Edit: I just remembered the ~= randomly, tried it, and pasted it.

But I just googled a bit (I had curiosity and found [This](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/), it's quite interesting)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of `~=`! To think I've been making my life difficult all this time by combining `=`, `^=`, `*=` and `$=` all this time!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that it only matches `cols-1` and *not* `cols-16` without relying on the `cols-16` style overriding the `cols-1` style (below), you could:

```
[data-whatever='cols-1'],
[data-whatever^='cols-1 '],
[data-whatever*='cols-1 '],
[data-whatever$='cols-1'] {
    background: red;
}
```

This matches `data-whatever="cols-1"`, `data-whatever="... cols-1"`, `data-whatever="cols-1 ..."` or `data-whatever="... cols-1 ..."`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBUSZ/2/) example.

Thanks to [aleation's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086021/1317805): `data-whatever~="cols-1"` achieves the same as the above in just one selector.

--

At any rate your `cols-16` styling could overwrite your `cols-1` styling anyway, depending on the order it was presented:

```
[data-whatever*='cols-1'] {
    background: red;
}

[data-whatever*='cols-16'] {
    background: blue;
}
```

/* cols-1 will be red. cols-16 will be blue */

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBUSZ/1/) example.